# reconnect immediately in Apache MQ over mqtt protocol

Tags: android, activemq-classic, mqtt

when my connection is alive at `Active Mq` and just in case if my 3G network link goes down in my mobile app and then i try to reconnect on the same connection string , i am not be able to connect and i can see a live connection in `Active MQ`. my app only get a chance to reconnect once that session at server get destroyed automatically and then it takes lot of time in reconnecting.

i have used session clean to **false** and QoS to **1** now is there anything to set so that i can reconnect immediately.

so is there a way to reconnect to server immediately ?

[image]

**edit**

i am getting following error in server log for above cases

```
javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException: Broker: localhost - Client: sf/new already connected from tcp://122.170.81.252:25330
```

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ?  Did you enable link stealing on the MQTT TransportConnector in your ActiveMQ config?

Comment: I m using `ActiveMQ 5.9.1` , i m not sure bout the enable link stealing can please tell me about this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the values of `Keep Alive` (higher) and also `Clean Session` (active).
This problem usually happens when not using clean session and a low keep alive value, so the broker hasn't clean up your client id before a reconnection.